# byte string too long error in Python using pypyodbc 1.3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, openshift

**Getting byte string too long** error while saving more than 127 characters in Unix environment while using pypyodbc 1.3.4 and Python Anaconda 3.5.

Gone through this link [Byte string too long PyPyOdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46134314/byte-string-too-long-pypyodbc) and applied the fix as stated but still issue persists.

I am trying to save more than 127 characters. Database is MS Sql Server. Column type is varchar MAX or nvarchar MAX (I tried with both).

Saving 127 orless than 127 characters is fine and working.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue with NVARCHAR(MAX) on MS SQL and pypyodbc 1.3.4:

```
    cursor.execute("insert into mytable (my_nvarchar_max_column) values (?)", "some long text here......")
```

fails with 'byte string too long' error.

Passing the string as a byte array works:

```
cursor.execute("insert into mytable (my_nvarchar_max_column) values (?)", 
"some long text here......".encode('utf8'))
```